# Handle "API usage limit" errors in eBay trading API

Tags: error-handling, ebay-api

While developing a trading application which proficiently handles API error conditions, I'm now focused on the class of API errors regarding usage limits.

The [Trading API errors list](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/Errors/ErrorMessages.htm) is far too extended to me; according to the list, we have the following error codes:

- error 518: Your application has exceeded usage limit on this call, [...]
- error 18000:  You have exceeded your daily request limit, therefore you will be unable to make additional requests for the remainder of the day.
- error 218050: Users of this application are limited to a number of calls they can make on a daily, hourly and 6-minute basis. [...]
- error 21919144: Maximum Call Limit Exceeded
- error 21919165: Maximum Call Limit Exceeded.

I want to be sure which of these errors my application should handle automatically, if not all. I'm particularly worried if higher error code numbers could be less consolidated and more prone to change their meaning over future API versions.

Worth considering, the Trading API errors list linked above doesn't contextualize the meaning of the errors, so their associated textual description could be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

My guess, Handle them all Automatically.

If your concerned for changes to error code, I don't see that as likely. They would rather create another error code then break/force changes on all the apps out there.

Besides you have an error message to compare too. If it doesn't match, then you could ignore / have fallback handle routine.

Finally, you could do back and read old versions / change log for the error codes. you will be able to tell how often they redefine these errors.

Comment: That's a good guess, in fact I've never seen a change-log on the eBay API regarding re-enumeration of error codes. My script now handles all the errors.